# Software centre neither update does not work on 12.04

Tags: apt, software-center, package-management, dpkg

```
m@samsung:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
[sudo] password for m: 
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial': Is a directory
m@samsung:~$ sudo apt-get clean
m@samsung:~$ sudo apt-get update
N: Ignoring file 'gnomebaker.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnomebaker.list (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
m@samsung:~$ sudo apt-get install software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
software-center is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up update-notifier-common (0.119ubuntu8.6) ...
Bus error (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing update-notifier-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier:
 update-notifier depends on update-notifier-common (= 0.119ubuntu8.6); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing update-notifier (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 update-notifier
N: Ignoring file 'gnomebaker.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnomebaker.list (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
m@samsung:~$
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your question?

Comment: my software centre is not starting at all...also update doesn;t run

Comment: Please edit your question with more information and dont touch the editing and the tags, they are just fine the way they are.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that your `rm` command has failed. Try `rm -rf` to recursively delete the directories.